# Elementary relationships between finite-dimensional subspaces and finite-codimensional subspaces

Tags: banach-spaces

I have an elementary question about finite-dimensional subspaces and finite-codimensional subspaces. This question may be known.

Question. Let $U$ be a finite-dimensional subspace of an infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Is there a finite-codimensional subspace $V$ of $X$ such that $U\cap V=\{0\}$ and $$\|u\|\leq (1+\epsilon)\|u+v\|$$ for every $u\in U, v\in V$ ?

Comment: (Of course the extra condition on $U \cap V$ is unnecessary, since, if $u \in U \cap V$, then your inequality gives $\|u\| \le (1 + \epsilon)\|u - u\| = 0$.  Also there's no need to specify infinite dimensionality, since, if $X$ is finite dimensional, then you may take $V = 0$.)

Comment: The condition $U\cap V=\{0\}$ is necessary, LSpice.

Comment: My inequality implies that $U\cap V=\{0\}$. You are right, LSpice. But how to prove the result?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $(u_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ be a $\delta$-net for $S_{U}(\delta>0$ will be specified later). For each $i$, choose $x^{*}_{i}\in S_{X^{*}}$ such that $\langle x^{*}_{i},x_{i}\rangle=1$. Let $V=\cap_{i=1}^{n}Ker(x^{*}_{i})$. Then $V$ is the required finite-codimensional subspace.